# Visual Studio Express 2013 to 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I am having issues porting visual Studio Express solutions over to Visual Studio 2017. I have attempted to follow the advice in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b966a280-362f-4adc-b902-e62d46c597a5/upgrade-project-from-vs-2015-to-vs-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral) article which has not solved the issue.

When I load my solution in 2017, I get an error stating "one or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly" with the following output:

> C:\Users\mikegjohn\Documents\Service Hub\Service_Hub\WindowsApplication1\Service_Hub.vbproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Users\mikegjohn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_825df01c\devenv.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.  C:\Users\mikegjohn\Documents\Service Hub\Service_Hub\WindowsApplication1\Service_Hub.vbproj

My solution explorer shows nothing and i cannot view any of the properties.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "SSDT" seems to indicate that your VS2017 installation is missing some features. Use VS2017 installer again to check.

Comment: That has sorted it! I added in the SQL modules which were left out of the main installation - thanks!

Comment: post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this with the help of Lex Li Jun. I reinstalled a number of SQL modules which were left out on the standard VS2017 package and this solved my problem!